# How to keep phonegap application open when pressing back button in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I'm building a phonegap application for my blackberry.  When I have the application open and I press the back button, the application terminates entirely, instead of just being "minimized" and allowed to sit in memory. So next time I click on the application, I have to login instead of seeing the last page I was on.

Is there a way to cause the blackberry back button to "minimize" instead of complete termination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BlackBerry Java applications the 'Hang Up' button is the standard UI request to minimize the application. Try that first. You should only override the function of the back button to minimize instead of exit if the application cannot or should not cleanly exit.

One of the most annoying behaviors for applications is if they don't exit when requested.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few onEvents that are provided by Blackberry's api to essentially background the application when someone tries to pop the screen off the display stack.  It's been a while since I've done this but I have done this personally.  I believe I used onObscured.. reference: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onObscured()

There are other events on there just carefully read through the api and instead of this.close() the screen do something like UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();

Answer (score 0):

I have few more observations. Back button exits the application only on 6.0 (OS) phones. But it doesn't exit on 7.0 phones.

In order to avoid issue on 6.0 ,You can over ride the back button functionality in your .js file with below code.

```
blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK,function() {
   //keep your code here
    alert("back key pressed");
   //For example..
   //if you want to navigate to particular page(say previous.html) on back button,you can use
    window.location.replace("previous.html");
    //you can also use
    history.back(); // To navigate to previous page as per page navigation.        
return false;
});
```

To get this event in your .js file you need to add below line in your config.xml

```
<feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
```